# How to pixelate a BufferedImage so it looks like that?

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel, bufferedimage, pixelate

I am doing Image Processing and I want to pixelate an Image which was dithered before but it should still look like the original. Here I show you some examples what Iam doing right now and what I want it to look like:

[image: Michael Jackson - normal]

That is the Image I want to modify.

[image: Michael Jackson - Dithered]

Thats the image after beeing dithered by the "floyd steinberg dithering".

[image: Michael Jackson- What I want it to look like]

Thats how he should look at the end after beeing pixelated.

[image: Michael Jackson- What my image looks like]

And thats how my image looks like after pixelating. I dont really know what to do so it looks like the image above.

I searched up the whole internet and I tried every pixelating algorithm. Thats the class Iam using at the moment:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public final class ImageUtil {

public static BufferedImage pixelate(BufferedImage imageToPixelate, int pixelSize) {
    BufferedImage pixelateImage = new BufferedImage(
        imageToPixelate.getWidth(),
        imageToPixelate.getHeight(),
        imageToPixelate.getType());

    for (int y = 0; y < imageToPixelate.getHeight(); y += pixelSize) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageToPixelate.getWidth(); x += pixelSize) {
            BufferedImage croppedImage = getCroppedImage(imageToPixelate, x, y, pixelSize, pixelSize);
            Color dominantColor = getDominantColor(croppedImage);
            for (int yd = y; (yd < y + pixelSize) && (yd < pixelateImage.getHeight()); yd++) {
                for (int xd = x; (xd < x + pixelSize) && (xd < pixelateImage.getWidth()); xd++) {
                    pixelateImage.setRGB(xd, yd, dominantColor.getRGB());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return pixelateImage;
}

public static BufferedImage getCroppedImage(BufferedImage image, int startx, int starty, int width, int height) {
    if (startx < 0) startx = 0;
    if (starty < 0) starty = 0;
    if (startx > image.getWidth()) startx = image.getWidth();
    if (starty > image.getHeight()) starty = image.getHeight();
    if (startx + width > image.getWidth()) width = image.getWidth() - startx;
    if (starty + height > image.getHeight()) height = image.getHeight() - starty;
    return image.getSubimage(startx, starty, width, height);
}

public static Color getDominantColor(BufferedImage image) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter = new HashMap<>(100);
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int currentRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int count = colorCounter.getOrDefault(currentRGB, 0);
            colorCounter.put(currentRGB, count + 1);
        }
    }
    return getDominantColor(colorCounter);
}

private static Color getDominantColor(Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter) {
    int dominantRGB = colorCounter.entrySet().stream()
        .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
        .get()
        .getKey();
    return new Color(dominantRGB);
}
}
```

And thats how I start it:

```
ImageUtil.pixelate(selectedImage, 3);
```

I appreciate your help and tell me if something is not clear or I need to add something to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the algorithmic stages you may apply:

- Down-sample original image - reduce resolution to about 200x200.
- Apply Palette with 16 colors with dithering.
  Check [rgb2ind](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) MATLAB documentation for details.
  In the example below, I found the palette using the reference image from your post.
- Resize up by a factor of x3 in each axis using **nearest neighbor** method to create the pixelate effect.

MATLAB implementation:

```matlab
% Palette of 16 colors
P = [  0     0     0
     160    80    44
     210   122   170
      14    16    83
     254   254   254
     255   113     0
      99    48    13
       1    86   158
       4    93    13
     192   192   192
      75    75    75
     233   165     0
     167    85   115
      85    15   105
       1   178   255
     116    11     7];

%Read original image
I = imread('I.jpg');

%Resize original image to resolution 200x200
J = imresize(I, [200, 200]);

% Convert shrunk RGB image to indexed image using palette P.
[IND, map] = rgb2ind(J, double(P)/255, 'dither'); %figure;imagesc(IND);colormap(map);axis image

% Convert from indexed image to RGB
RGB = ind2rgb(IND, map); %figure;imshow(RGB);

% Resize RGB by factor of x3 in each axis, use nearest-neighbor interpolation.
K = imresize(RGB, 3, 'nearest');

figure;imshow(K);
```

Result:
[image]

There are some differences from your reference (probably due to different colors reduction algorithm).

Comment: Wow thank you very much! What neirest neighbour method did u use ?

Comment: "Nearest neighbor" is the interpolation method of `resize`. When you resize an image, you can use bi-cubic interpolation, bi-linear interpolation... and "nearest neighbor", that takes the nearest pixel without any interpolation.

Comment: I found a JAVA example [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2019/01/image-scaling-options-in-java/)

Comment: I forgot to thank you!! It looks better right now but still weird. I try to figure out why